# Java spring boot add json file

Tags: java

I'm a beginner at Java,
How do I tell the code to read a file from the current location the jar is on?

I tried

```
private static String getRunningFolder(){
    try {
        String result = new File(Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
                .toURI()).getPath();
        result = result.replace("/classes", "");
        return result;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
        return "";
    }
}
```

but that only works when debugging in IDE - Not from cmd: java -jar

Comment: It's not depending on where the jar is but where you ran the command. You can run it from anywhere if you give the right classpath in argument of your java command.
I prefer mvn:spring-boot run if you use maven or gradle bootRun if you have such tools on your project.

Comment: new File("").getAbsolutePath();